# How to move text cursor to the next location quickly?

Tags: microsoft-word, macros, autohotkey, libreoffice-writer, cursor

I need to fill text inside the quote brackets, which locate in unpredictable places in the file. Is there a way to fill them quickly without having moving the cursor manually?

> NASA, “” [Stagnation Temperature,]
>   http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/BGH/stagtmp.html
>
> Sét
>
> “” [Lightning Captured @ 7,207 Fps,]
>   http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxQt8ivUGWQ
>   NOVA, “” [Lightning: Expert Q&A,] http://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/earth/dwyer-lightfiing.html
>   JGR, “” [Computation of the diameter of a lightning return stroke] 
>   http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1029/JB073i006p01889 /abstract

I imagine this can be done by replacing all the brackets with the brackets contain an invisible mark, so that after filling a bracket, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> will move the cursor to the next one immediately, same as how Excel works. Since <kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> have already had their function, I guess a different key binding is require to do this.

Is there a way to do this? May a macro or an AutoHotKey script be able do this? I use Word and Libre Office.

Comment: what is "quote bracket"? What about pressing CTRL+F and typing the text you need to jump to? (Next time it would be just CTRL+F and Enter). What is your example about?

Comment: @MátéJuhász the quotation marks? I think just using tab is quicker and more convenient as if they are just empty fields. The example is about the places that those marks can appear.

Answer (score 1):

Set the brackets you want to jump the cursor at to a particular style and then record a macro that does a search for the next instance of that style.

I'm not sure what version of Word you are using but in general to do this start recording a macro, go to Edit --> Find, select the "More" button, and then select the "Format" button. Under "Format", you'll find "Style". You can select the style you want it to search for. Finally add the macro to a shortcut on the toolbar.